# Windows services (Services.msc) not accepting logon user account password but using some default password

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-service, windows-registry

I've installed a Record Manager software over my Windows Server and after installation I am able to see a service generated by the installer in Service Control Manager ***Services.msc*** which at first instance seems to have following parameters:

> **StartUp Type** as *Manual*
>
> **Log On As** as *Local System*..
>
> **Status** as *Running*,

While I need to change these parameters so in Service properties I am trying to change and set new values as:

> **StartUp Type** as *Automatic*
>
> **Log On As**  a *UserAccount*  *(with a Service user account from Active Directory and a valid password)*

Now, problem arises once I add this service user account and password then I click on `Apply` and after clicking on `Apply` automatically the `New password` disappears and again I am able to see the `Old password`.

I am not sure from where this password is getting overrided, maybe it's somewhere from Windows System Registry. Well, I've tried the same thing with other services and guess what that is the **ERROR** with any services...
Any suggestions??

**Thanks in Advance!**

Server : Windows Server 2016 (64 bit)

Comment: `after clicking on Apply automatically the New password disappears and again I am able to see the Old password`. Actually Windows does not display the password.

Comment: Yes, that's correct but the length of my password is small and while clicking on `Apply` the original length seems to be appearing again.. So, while I restart the service it fails due to wrong credentials ...

Comment: The number of dots you see are not an indication that the password is changing. That's just Windows being Windows.

Comment: Okay, so how can I make my password to be accepted in place...? Can I set it via command or registry..?

Comment: I don't think that's your problem.  But you can set the password using the `sc config` command, e.g, `sc config myservice password= newpassword`.

Comment: Did you remember to specify the domain when entering the username?  It needs to be either `domain\username` or `username@domain.com`

Comment: So, while adding user from Active directory it automatically takes parameter as `username@domain.com`  however, I tried this way also `domain\username` like I usually do but it didn't worked...
Have not tested using `sc config` command will try it once...

Comment: Nope.. `sc config` command showed a successful message but didn't worked.. Still I am able to see 15 dots in `password` field and again I tried to change it manually but the same behaviour after clicking on `Apply`

Comment: The number of dots shown doesn't mean anything.  It isn't the actual length of the stored password.

Comment: So, @HarryJohnston do you think that password is getting changed?? How can I verify this? Any command or something to check the password entries for a particular service?

Comment: There's no need to verify it.  If you're not getting an error message, the stored password is getting changed.  Something else is preventing the service from starting, you just need to figure out what it is, e.g., the username is incorrect, the user doesn't have the "Log on as a service" privilege, the account is disabled or expired, , etc.